# Proof explanation for how this criteria shows exactness

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

This is about a proof from *Homological Algebra on a Complete Intersection...* by Eisenbud.

Here, $A$ is a Noetherian commutative ring.

To show exactness at $\bar F$, we must show that $\operatorname{Im} \bar \psi \subset \ker \bar \varphi$ and that $\ker \bar \varphi \subset \operatorname{Im} \bar \psi$.

How does the highlighted text below imply this?

---

> [image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\varphi \psi = x$, reducing modulo $x$ we find $\bar{\varphi} \bar{\psi} = 0$, so $\operatorname{im} \bar{\psi} \subseteq \ker \bar{\varphi}$.

Conversely, let $\bar{u} \in \ker \bar{\varphi}$, and $u$ any lift of $\bar{u}$ to $F$.  Take $\kappa: A \to F$ determined by $\kappa(1) = u$, so that $\bar{\kappa}(1) = \bar{u}$. Then by assumption $\bar{\varphi} \bar{\kappa} = 0$.  Suppose we could show from this that $\bar{\kappa}$ factors through $\bar{\psi}$, i.e., $\bar{\kappa} = \bar{\psi} \bar{\gamma}$ for some $\bar{\gamma}: B \to \bar{G}$.  Then $\bar{u} = \bar{\kappa}(1) = \bar{\psi} (\bar{\gamma}(1))$, so $\bar{u} \in \operatorname{im} \bar{\psi}$.  Therefore, $\ker \bar{\varphi} \subseteq \operatorname{im} \bar{\psi}$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Do you know why $\bar \varphi \bar \kappa = \overline{\varphi \kappa}$ implies there exists $\gamma: K \to G$ such that $\varphi \kappa = x \gamma$?

Comment: The point is that $\overline{\varphi \kappa} = \bar{\varphi} \bar{\kappa} = 0$, i.e, $\equiv 0 \pmod{x}$.  So $\varphi \kappa $ lands in the submodule $xG$, and $\varphi \kappa = x \gamma$ for some $\gamma$.

Comment: Got it. Also, where does the assumption that $(x)/(x^2)$ is free over $B$ come into play?

Comment: You need it to "divide" by $x$.  Let $a = \kappa - \psi \gamma$.  Then $xa = 0$, so $a$ annihilates the module $(x)/(x^2)$.  But $(x)/(x^2)$ is free, hence faithful, i.e., $\operatorname{Ann}_{A/(x)}((x)/(x^2)) = \{0\}$, so $a = 0$ in $A/(x)$.

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks.